# set a maven plugin to not execute inside the main buildcycle

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I am using maven-jaxb2-plugin to generate sources from wsdl files. I would like to execute this plugin manually and then upload the generated files in the repository but I don't want the plugin to be executed when I am building the project normally.

How can I configure the execution to achieve this?

I am looking for something in the lines of:

> mvn jaxb2:generate (generates the sources)
>
> mvn package (ignores the
> plugin)

My best idea so far is commenting and uncommenting the plugin in the pom.xml, but I feel there has to be a cleaner way but I just can't find it in the documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you just create separate maven project to build sources (and maybe wsdl client),  mvn install it and use that in your main project as a dependency?

Comment: The goal of this is to simplify things specially for other people working in the project. I appreciate the idea, but having a different project feels like more overwork that commenting/uncommenting.

Comment: What is the exact plugin you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you should tell Maven to skip the default execution for this plugin, like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.13.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution> 
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

As this plugin by default binds itself to a phase, we just force this *default* execution id to the *none* phase, in order for this plugin not to be executed during a normal build (`mvn clean package`).
A specific plugin call (`mvn jaxb2:generate`) will still be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `default-cli` execution ID like this:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>default-cli</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>generate</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <!-- your config here -->
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Not tested, but I hope it gets you close.

[Maven docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-default-execution-ids.html)

Comment: That gets executed during the main buildcycle. I've read the documentation regarding default-cli but I don't really understand what it does.

Comment: You tried it? And you are sure that the execution that runs, as reported in the logs, has execution ID == `default-cli` and not something else?